# Davmail Java terminates with SIGSEGV after 11.10 Upgrade

Tags: 11.10, java, dbus, davmail

One of my favorite programs, davmail, crashes now after upgrading to 11.10. Just checking if there is a quick fix before I submit a bug report. Thanks.

```
$ davmail 
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff9e08d46b0, pid=7998, tid=140711267337984
#
# JRE version: 6.0_23-b23
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.11pre
# Distribution: Ubuntu oneiric (development branch), package 6b23~pre10-0ubuntu5
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libdbus-1.so.3+0x246b0]
[error occurred during error reporting (printing problematic frame), id 0xb]

# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/pcm/hs_err_pid7998.log
GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

Comment: what version of davmail are you using..... I tried with the java-7-openjdk-amd64 and I still get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by installing **openjdk-7-jre**, and then linking the `/usr/bin/davmail` script to use the JDK1.7 java binary.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working by me as well - was having trouble with it since I've upgraded to 11.10...

Answer (score 1):

After installing openjdk7, do this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
```